# How to Render jfreechart in html mail as inline without saving chart as image in server side

Tags: jakarta-mail, jfreechart

Am trying to send an email with the chart created from jfreechart component and sending html mail using javax.mail.
my requirement is to render a jfreechart in html mail as inline without saving chart as image in server side.

Is this possible and how can we do it in java?

Answer (score 0):

`JFreeChart` has [`ChartUtilities`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtilities.html) with methods like `writeChartAsPNG()` that write to an `OutputStream`, and `javax.mail` has [`MimeUtility`](http://geronimo.apache.org/maven/specs/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec/1.5/apidocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html) with methods like `encode()` that write to an `OutputStream`, like they show [here](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2011/08/how-to-encode-and-decode-in-base64-using-java). You should be able to wrap the chart stream in the encoder stream.

Comment: Write the chart to a ByteArrayOutputStream then use JavaMail's ByteArrayDataSource to attach the image.  JavaMail will take care of encoding the data for you so you don't need to use those MimeUtility methods.